# Outlook Save multiple attachments using the subject line, and incrementing that name

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I've spent a couple of weeks playing with VBA, I am not by any means an expert on this.

What I'm looking for is a modification of this code.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachments()
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim i As Integer
Dim lngCount As Integer
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolderpath As String
Dim strFileName As String
Dim objSubject As String
Dim strDeletedFiles As String
' Get the path to your My Documents folder
'strFolderpath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
On Error Resume Next
' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
' Get the collection of selected objects.
Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection
' The attachment folder needs to exist
' You can change this to another folder name of your choice
' Set the Attachment folder.
strFolderpath = "C:\Users\demkep\Documents\"
' Check each selected item for attachments.
For Each objMsg In objSelection
'Set FileName to Subject
objSubject = objMsg.Subject
Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
lngCount = objAttachments.Count
If lngCount > 0 Then
' Use a count down loop for removing items
' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
' confused and only every other item is removed.
For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
' Get the file name.
strFileName = objSubject & ".pdf"
' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
strFile = strFolderpath & strFileName
Debug.Print strFile
' Save the attachment as a file.
objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
Next i
End If
Next
ExitSub:
Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing 
Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

It is the closest to what I am trying to accomplish.

However when I get an email with multiple attachments, it will simply overwrite the last file.  if possible. I'd like it to save (sometimes up to 30 .pdf files) as **`"emailsubject, emailsubject(1), emailsubject(2), emailsubject(3)"`** etc...

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not changing the filename within the loop. Something like

```
strFileName = objSubject & "(" & i & ").pdf"
```

should take care of that.

If you only want numbers if there is more than one attachment you can check lngCount before setting the name or use `IIf`

```
If lngCount > 1 Then
    strFileName = objSubject & "(" & i & ").pdf"
Else
    strFileName = objSubject & ".pdf"
End If
```

Or

```
strFileName = objSubject & IIf(lngCount>1, "(" & i & ")", "") & ".pdf"
```

---

You shouldn't use `On Error Resume Next` on your whole sub btw.

Comment: Thank you for this, This is saving me about an hour of busy work per day. worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Function that will do exactly what you need

```
Function UniqueName(FilePath As String) As String

    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")

    Dim FileName As String
        FileName = FilePath

    Dim Ext As String
        Ext = Chr(46) & FSO.GetExtensionName(FilePath)

    Dim i As Long
        i = 1

    Do While FSO.FileExists(FileName)
        FileName = Left(FilePath, Len(FilePath) - Len(Ext)) & " (" & i & ")" & Ext
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    UniqueName = FileName

End Function
```

And change this `strFile = strFolderpath & strFileName` To `strFile = UniqueName(strFolderpath & strFileName)`